# Handler socket timers on read/write

Tags: c++, sockets, timeout

How do you set timeouts with read and write (sockets)? and test them?

```
struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 3;
timeout.tv_usec = 0;
setsockopt (fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout,
  sizeof(timeout));
setsockopt (fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *)&timeout,
    sizeof(timeout));
string temp;
while (1) {
    char buf [20];
    ssize_t e = read(fd, buf, 20);
            // convert current buf into string
            // add current string to temp
            // check if end of temp == \r\n\r\n
            // if yes break
}
```

So if I use telnet to test this, and type in 'hello', the console "hangs" because the read is blocking.  However when it hangs past 3 seconds, the timeout does nothing.  I want the read to close the connection after hanging for 3 seconds.  How do I do this?

Comment: `read()` will not close the connection, you have to check if read returned an error or `0` and then close the connection using `close(fd)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size is obviously wrong:

> ```
> setsockopt (fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&timeout,
>     sizeof(timeout) < 0);
> ```

Drop the `< 0`. You probably copy pasted from some if and then botched the parentheses.